# Difference between count(attribute) and count (*) using group by

Tags: sql

I haven't understood the difference between `count(*)` and count having an attribute as argument.
Here I make an example: there are two relationships:

```
project (id, name, number);
employee (ssn, name, surname);
working_on (employee_ssn,   project_id);
```

With `employee_ssn` which references `employee(ssn)` and `project_id` referencing `project(id)`.
Primary keys: `project(id)`, `employee(ssn)`, working_on (`employee_ssn`, `project_id`).
Now I have to find for each project, the id of the project, the name and the number of employees working on it.
A correct solution (found on the book) is this one:

```
select id, name, count (*)
from working_on join project on id=project_id
group by name, id
```

I have,'t understood why this solution is valid, shouldn't `count (*)` count all tuples? Why this way it gets the exact number of employees working on it?
I have written this solution instead:

```
select id, name, count (employee_ssn)
from working_on join project on id=project_id
group by name, id
```

Are the solutions equivalent?
And in general, there is a difference using `count (*)` and `count(attribute)`? Could you provide an example where these two syntaxes produce different results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out two differences till now -

1. as eric mentioned above, count(col) doesn't count null values whereas count (*) does.
2. It behaves differently in a join query.

Consider a situation where i need to join employee and department table, and i need to find count of employees in each department.

2.a.

```
SELECT     DPT.ID 
,          COUNT(*) EMP_COUNT
FROM       DEPARTMENT DPT
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE E
ON         DPT.ID = E.DEPARTMENT_ID
GROUP BY   DPT.ID;
```

In the above query, it will not return those records where employee table count=0.

2.b.

```
SELECT     DPT.ID 
,          COUNT(E.DEPARTMENT_ID) EMP_COUNT
FROM       DEPARTMENT DPT
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE E
ON         DPT.ID = E.DEPARTMENT_ID
GROUP BY   DPT.ID;
```

If you use count(E.DEPARTMENT_ID) instead of count(*), this time it will give records even when employee table count=0.

2.c.

```
SELECT     DPT.ID 
,          COUNT(DPT.ID) EMP_COUNT
FROM       DEPARTMENT DPT
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE E
ON         DPT.ID = E.DEPARTMENT_ID
GROUP BY   DPT.ID;
```

This is the interesting part, when you use COUNT(DPT.ID), since DPT.ID is column of department, here again records where employee table count=0 will NOT be considered.

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count):

> *COUNT(expr)*
>
> Returns a count of the number of non-`NULL` values of *expr* in the rows
>   retrieved by a `SELECT` statement.

---

> *COUNT(*)* is somewhat different in that it returns a count of the
>   number of rows retrieved, whether or not they contain `NULL` values.

In other words:

`COUNT(expr)` will return the number of rows that do not have a `NULL` value for *expr*.

`COUNT(*)` will return the total number of returned rows.

Whether or not you are using a `GROUP BY` clause is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

`count(*)` will count a NULL and `count(attribute)` will not. So the only difference will appear when you have NULL values in a column

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, `COUNT(*)` will count the total number of rows retrieved, however, `COUNT(attribute_name)` will only count the number of non-null values.
Actually, both of them counts the number of non-null values but, since in relational databases there should be no row -tuple- having all its values as NULL(it should have a primary key which can't be NULL), `COUNT(*)` will always return the total number of rows in the table -relation- which constitutes, the number of values of the primary key column -attribute-